# How to split the string seperate in one contet

Tags: php, string

I'm working on my PHP to parse the contents as I'm using simple_html_dom. I want to split the strings between the time and the programme title.

Here is the strings:

```
2:00 PM                                               Local Programming
```

I want to split the strings separate to make it something like this:

```
<span id="time1">2:00 PM </span> - <span id="title1">Local Programming</span>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$links = $row['links'];
$html = file_get_html($links);

$base = $row['links'];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($str);

if ($html->find('li[id=row1-24]', 0) == True)
{
  $title1 = $html->find('li[id=row1-24]', 0)->plaintext; // with this
}

echo $title1;
?>
```

Can you please tell me how I can split the strings into two different variables so i can output them in the PHP?

Comment: Why not use regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
$title1 = preg_split("/ {4,}/",$title1);
echo '<span id="time1">' . $title1[0] . '</span> - <span id="title1">' . $title1[1] . '</span>';
```

This splits the string into an array on four or more spaces.

The returned array has two items in it like this: `["2:00 PM","Local Programming"]`.

Then it uses the array to create the desired HTML markup and `echo`s it.

Comment: I can see that it have split between the time and the programme title, but it is only show the time without the programme title. How do you split the time and programme title to make the output like this `<span id="time1">2:00 PM </span> - <span id="title1">Local Programming</span>`?

Comment: @user3494862: `$title1[0]` is the time and `$title1[1]` is the title.  `preg_split` returns an array with two elements in it.

Comment: well what I have got is 
`<span id="time1"></span> - <span id="title1">2:30 PM</span>`. it doesn't show the programme title in the output. Any idea?

Comment: @user3494862: Maybe you will work for you: `echo '<span id="time1">' . $title1[1] . '</span> - <span id="title1">' . $title1[2] . '</span>';`.

Comment: thank you very much for this, I can see that it is working now. You have saved me a lot of time to do the hours work instead of wasting of time. Thanks for the help! (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions you could do something like this:

```
// using regex grab the time and title separately
preg_match('/(\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s?\w{2})\s+([\w\s\d]+)', trim($title1), $matches);

// matches[1] is the time and matches[2] is the title
echo "<span id=\"time1\">$matches[1]</span> - <span id=\"title1\">$matches[2]</span>";
```